# Graphical Bug with Java Swing - Drawing from a list makes elements jump around

Tags: java, swing, graphics

So I was messing with Swing for the first time in a while and I came across a strange issue. So I am adding "shapes" to a list every so often, and then in the paintComponent method of a JPanel I am looping through the list and drawing the shapes. I also draw a shape outside of the for loop for testing purposes.

What happens is the shapes in the for loop will jump around the screen randomly. This only happens when the shapes are drawn in this loop.

What I have tried already:

- Updating graphics drivers for both the integrated GPU and discrete GPU
- Using java.util.Timer instead of Swing Timer
- Using Thread/Runnable
- Using things other than ArrayList, such as LinkedList, Vector, and a normal Array.
- Trimmed literally everything out of my code except the basics, which is what we're left with here. I was drawing more complex things before when I noticed it.
- Changed the timing (PERIOD variable, in millis). It will get worse if I increase or decrease it.
- Changed from using System time in milliseconds to the System time in nanoseconds, converted to milliseconds. I know this should be the same but I was running out of ideas.

Here is a gif of the problem (15 seconds long):
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBTJK.gif)

You'll notice that the small squares will jump around at random intervals. This should not occur. I'm just trying to "spawn" a square at random coords.

Here is the code in a pastebin:
[code](https://paste.whitefire.in/view/dOk0AjlU57)

I have included all 3 classes in this order: the JPanel class, the Main class (extends JFrame), and the shape class

If any of the links don't work, inform me and I will promptly post other links.

Thanks.

Comment: Please no links to code. Remember that we're volunteers, and you will want to make it as easy as possible to have your questions answered.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") really should include the desired behavior, and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please create and post your [mcve] so we can play with a small compilable and runnable program and so that we can test your code ourselves, and hopefully modify it so that it will work. Note that we **do not want to see your entire program**, nor should you post a link to a code repository. Instead keep it small, keep it simple, and make it functioning.

Comment: I figured having a lot of code on a separate page would be easier (I'd prefer that), but thanks. I also wasn't sure where the issue was. Will remember in the future. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 0):

This setup ...

```
@Override
public final void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (this.startTime == -1L) {
        this.startTime = Main.timeMillis();
    }
    final long timeDiff = Main.timeMillis() - this.startTime;
    if (this.circlesIndex <= 19 && timeDiff > 2000) {
        final int randX = this.rand.nextInt(this.WIDTH);
        final int randY = this.rand.nextInt(this.HEIGHT);
        this.testShapes.add(new TestShape(randX, randY));
        this.startTime = Main.timeMillis();
    }
    for (TestShape ts : this.testShapes) {
        ts.draw(g);
    }
    g2.setColor(Color.gray);
    g2.fill3DRect(350, 400, 100, 60, true);
}

@Override
public final void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
    x++;
    if (x > WIDTH) {
        x = -50;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

is wrong.

Paint is for painting - you should not modify the state of the UI from inside any paint method, do this within your `ActionListener`. The problem is, your component can be painted for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control or know about

Comment: Thanks. I moved all the stuff except the draw call and the Graphics2D calls into the actionPerformed method. However, the problem still persists.

Comment: @Nahr I have no issues, but you also don't supply `this.circlesIndex` so I'm not running the same code

Comment: Sorry. It was left over from my code before I stripped everything away. It does nothing anymore. In this code it's literally just a 0. @MadProgrammer